# Drawing UIButton image via CGContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, core-graphics, cgcontext

In order to display a progress circle on a button, I draw an arc into a `CGContext`, then pass it to `UIImage` and finally to the `UIButton` image. However all it draws is a filled square:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, myButton.frame.size.width, myButton.frame.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1);
[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0. blue:0. alpha:1.0] setStroke];
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0] setFill];
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, rect.size.width/2., rect.size.height/2.);
CGContextAddArc(ctx,
                rect.size.width/2., // centerX
                rect.size.height/2.,  // centerY
                rect.size.width, // radius
                0, // start Angle
                M_PI/2., // end Angle
                1); // clockwise
CGContextDrawPath(ctx,kCGPathFillStroke);

UIImage *progressImg=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[myButton setImage:progressImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Why do I get a filled square and not a filled partial arc? Is that the best way to draw a progress-bar as a circle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arc radius is wrong. The actual arc is being drawn way outside your context bounds. Change

```
CGContextAddArc(ctx,
                rect.size.width/2., // centerX
                rect.size.height/2.,  // centerY
                rect.size.width, // radius
                0, // start Angle
                M_PI/2., // end Angle
                1); // clockwise
```

to

```
CGContextAddArc(ctx,
                rect.size.width/2., // centerX
                rect.size.height/2.,  // centerY
                rect.size.width/2., // radius
                0, // start Angle
                M_PI/2., // end Angle
                1); // clockwise
```

Also, note that depending on your button type, you may wind up with the image treated as a *template* rather than the actual image you drew. To fix that, you'd say (before using the image in the button):

```
progressImg = 
    [progressImg imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: Also I'd suggest drawing a final line segment back to the center.